# Suggested System Parameter Settings for Solaris 10 client doing heavy NFS access

Tags: nfs, kernel, solaris-10

I have a client that has an application that is heavily utilizing NFS filesystem access on a T2000 32GByte 1GHz-4core SPARC Solaris 10 system.  The client wants to get better performance out of the box.  The system has no parameter modifications (in /etc/system) and I was wondering if there were some parameter changes that might make sense here to help the situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a [whole section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/817-0404/chapter3-1.html) of the Tunable Parameters Reference Manual devoted to NFS options.

Which ones you change and what values you set them to depends wholly on the way NFS is being utilized. However, if you have a high performance network and there are a lot of parallel operations happening, you'd probably have the most benefit from changing `nfs:nfs3_max_threads`.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth looking at is the[Solaris Internals wiki](http://solarisinternals.com/wiki), specifically the [NFS Server](http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/Application_Specific_Tuning#NFS_Server) section .. there are some useful notes about ZFS tuning as well (assuming ZFS is your underlying filesystem)

Do you know where the server is bottlenecked?  Can you profile the clients to see what they're waiting for?